# django charfield with default empty string is required in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with a Charfield:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    charfield = models.Charfield(max_length=5, default="")
    ...
```

I expect this field to be not required when using in the admin. But when I include this model to the admin, I have this field required. I could use `null=True, blank=True`, but I'm curious  Is it some kind of a bug or am I implementing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that's a bug. If you don't specify `blank=True`, some kind of non-empty value is required. The empty string, by definition, is an empty value; so Django quite correctly displays an error telling you to supply an actual value.

You do need to specify `blank=True` if you want the empty string to be allowed. But you don't need to specify `null=True`; indeed, as the docs show, you shouldn't use that on CharFields.

Comment: I want to the default value of a `Charfield` or `TextField` to be the empty string, so is redundant to set `default=''` when you have already set `blank=True` for `CharField` and `TextField` or `default=""` is required?

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. `default`, `null` and `blank` have different meanings.

`null` allows NULL value on database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

`blank` allows blank value on the model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank

Additionally, a ModelForm (used by admin) with `blank=True` sets the required field as false, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types